# Was not able to run cmd process from ASP.NET application hosted in IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, cmd, process

I was not able to run cmd process from back end of application with Process class hosted in IIS 10.0.

**Note**: I have found to start new process from IIS application pool need to add external options or privileges

1. Add administrator user in application pool identity
2. Allow to interact with desktop from **IIS Admin service**

After IIS 7.0 version there is no **IIS Admin service**. There is only **World Wide Web Publishing service**

I have tried
 Add Administrator user for application pool in IIS

Switch on an option Allow to interact with desktop from  **World Wide Web Publishing service**

My IIS version is 10.0

```cs
Process process = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();

processInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
processInfo.Arguments = $"/c python {NNModulePath}";
processInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
processInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
process.StartInfo = processInfo;
process.Start();
```

Actual result I was not able to run cmd process from back end side
Expected result  successfully run cmd process from back end side

Comment: What does "*not able to run*" mean? Do you get an exception?

Comment: @Crowcoder I doesn't receive any exception. Just it returs Exite code 1.

Comment: If you log into the server are you able to manually execute this?

Comment: So I just run application and it execute code. How to run it manually?

Comment: Run up a command prompt and type "python" followed by the relevant path as specified by `NNModulePath`

Comment: open a command prompt and put put your args in. Though, I think you just want to run python, not cmd.exe.

Comment: @Crowcoder yes actually I want to run module.py. With manually it works process starts successfully

Comment: change your process to run python, not cmd.

Comment: @Crowcoder the actual issue is ,that from IIS application you can not run other process. For that need to do some tricks.

Comment: Have you enabled load user profile in the app pool, or is that what you mean by "interact with desktop"?

Comment: Hi Grig, as a rule, please add any extra information to the question by editing it, rather than simply writing them in comments.  That way, new readers will be able to find all the info easily without having to read through all the comments, and you should get a better response.

Comment: @Crowcoder in Application pool Identity section I filled Administrator user. Allowed to interact  with desktop (Allow interact with window option locates in World Wide Web Publishing service

Comment: Yes, you already said that. I'm talking about "Load User Profile" though I doubt that will help either. Are you able to start any process at all that way? Maybe write a simple exe that writes an event log (by the way, have you checked the event log?).